# How can paly a specific sound for specific text/word on wordpress post by click or hover?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add a feature to my wordpress website. I searched a lot but nothing worked.

I have a LMS website and a language learning course. so i need to add Pronunciation for specific words. Pronunciation sound files should play with clicking or hovering on the words. And of course these words and sound files should be different in posts. I will be thankful for helping me.

Comment: Take a look at using a framework like https://howlerjs.com/ and the attach to the mouseOver event on your elements and trigger the sound. I guess the elements would be spans with a data-pronunciation tag or something that would contain the path to the file to play for that word.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example built on the suggestion I had in my comment;

```js
$('span[data-pronunciation]').mouseover(function() {
    var sound = new Howl({
      src: [$(this).attr('data-pronunciation')]
    });
    sound.play();
});
```

```css
span:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-pronunciation="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/cartoon/cartoon_boing.ogg">One</span> <span data-pronunciation="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/cartoon/clang_and_wobble.ogg">Two</span>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.14/howler.min.js"></script>
```